# Insertion of a JLabel in a container

Tags: java, swing, jframe, containers, jlabel

I have to create a window with a graphical interface in Java using Swing. Here I have tried to maximize and rename the window and this works. The problem is that then I tried to insert a JLabel but nothing is seen, why?

```
 package esercizio7;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Esercizio7 {

public static void main(String[] v){
JFrame f = new JFrame("Prenota il tuo biglietto!");
Container c = f.getContentPane();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
c.add(panel);
f.setSize(new Dimension(500,350));
f.show();
}}




public class testo extends JPanel {
public testo(){
super();
JLabel l = new JLabel("srgsgsrg");
add(l);}}
```

Comment: `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` should be `JPanel panel = new testo();` BTW: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: But where would the error of the nomenclature be? The class is written in upper case and the methods are written in lower case.
The only thing is that to put in the application all the code I had to put all the braces (}) otherwise it did not make me send. Anyway thanks for the fix, it works now.

Comment: *"The class is written in upper case"* Which part of `testo` is upper case? *"it works now"* Congrats. Glad you got it sorted. :)